# Windows Phone 8 Device cannot see IIS on connected laptop

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8

I can debug my app successfully on the windows phone 8 emulator but when I deploy it to an actual device it cannot see the wcf service.

The error I get is System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException

The service is running on IIS on my Windows 8 laptop. I am using the same IP address that I use from the emulator.

I opened all required ports in the firewall and even tried turning the firewall off.

All worked fine on my previous laptop. This is a new Lenovo I am setting up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the emulator co-resident with the IIS server? What IP address do you use - 192.168.x.x?

Comment: The emulator runs in a VM so I can't see how this is different from the phone i.e. they are both external to the pc. I use address 192.168.1.124 from both the emulator and the phone.

Comment: Still... The VM uses the network adapter of the host OS, so when it looks for its own IP address it may be bypassing some barriers. This may be something stupid, but could it be that some crapware firewall/antivirus from Lenovo is installed as well?